# Is there a way to replicate the Wix Repeater element in swift / xcode?

Tags: velo

I have created a webapp using Wix, which relies heavily on the repeater element to display content from a database inside a repeating element. Repeaters do pretty much exactly what I want, but I realize they are built on a pretty sophisticated API, and there's a lot of stuff making this happen in the background.

Ultimately for this project, a native iOS app is the end goal. However, I have no experience in xcode - but willing to learn. Before I get in too deep, is there any kind of functionality I could find to achieve something like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert Wix Repeater element to Xcode. But, you can make deep customization to your Wix elements by using [Wix Corvid](https://www.wix.com/corvid).

If you not familiar with it, it's is a developing platform integrated into the Wix ecosystem that allows users to build advanced sites. Among other things, it’s able to create and manage databases, build dynamic pages, host user-generated content and more.